# Two Way Volume Shadow Copy Service

Tags: windows, vss, cluster-shared-volumes

Can one use Windows Server VSS in a two-way configuration?

VSS from Volume A to Volume B is a "normal" mode of operation. But, can one do, at the same time, VSS from Volume B to Volume A?

That would be Peer to Peer (P2P) sync, I can do that with P2P tools like "[Resilio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resilio_Sync)". In a pretty slow amateurish fashion. I need the same but in "real-time". Servers will be in the same rack.

PS: Yes, I am aware I am trying to do the "clustering with no clustering".And we do not use VM's. Just two physical machines.

Comment: Two volumes as "masters" is not supported by VSS.

Comment: I assume means that is on one server?  I assume one VSS service is running per one server.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/429248/619307 And that seems to be an answer?